# Download attachments from the PR/CR via Web Mode CLI

Tags: download, attachment, cm-synergy

Is there a way to download attachments from the CR/PR in Rational Change Server via Web Mode CLI?
I know that is possible to do via the classic client's ccm, but in the Web Mode CLI it isn't possible in the same manner (i.e. **ccm *export*** does not exist or there is a permissions problem).

Regards,
Pawel

**EDIT:**
I eventually arrived at the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cat the contents of the object represented by its objectname, the problem was that the attachment's object name has a white space inside...

```
ccm query "is_attachment_of(cr('CR_PR_displayname'))" -u -f "%objectname %attachment_name %attachment_size"
```

then with the objectname of an attachment:

```
ccm cat objectname_of_an_attachment > C:\attachment_name
```

**attachment_name** - holds the name with extension

**attachment_size** - holds the size in Bytes